# Print function produces output only within main function

Tags: python

I know my post count looks suspicious but in my six years of coding I always found an answer by doing some research, this issue though has got me stumped so here goes my first post.

The problem I am facing is simple, I am using python to code a genetic algorithm for Hanabi game, while in other projects I used to print out some info normally so I can debug or ensure results are what expect them to be, in this project and for some very odd reason, whenever I use print() it does not produce an output in most cases, it does produce an output only if it is called from the main function, I will paste my code and result below:

```
 import sys
from hanabi_learning_environment import rl_env
from rule_agent_chromosome import RuleAgentChromosome
import os, contextlib



def run(num_episodes, num_players, chromosome, verbose=True):
    """Run episodes."""
    environment=rl_env.make('Hanabi-Full', num_players=num_players)
    game_scores = []
    print("TEST start of run")
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        observations = environment.reset()
        agents = [RuleAgentChromosome({'players': num_players},chromosome) for _ in range(num_players)]
        done = False
        episode_reward = 0
        while not done:
            for agent_id, agent in enumerate(agents):
                observation = observations['player_observations'][agent_id]
                action = agent.act(observation)
                if observation['current_player'] == agent_id:
                    assert action is not None   
                    current_player_action = action
                    if verbose:
                        print("Player",agent_id,"to play")
                        print("Player",agent_id,"View of cards",observation["observed_hands"])
                        print("Fireworks",observation["fireworks"])
                        print("Player",agent_id,"chose action",action)
                        print()
                else:
                    assert action is None
            # Make an environment step.
            observations, reward, done, unused_info = environment.step(current_player_action)
            if reward<0:
                reward=0 # we're changing the rules so that losing all lives does not result in the score being zeroed.
            episode_reward += reward
            
        if verbose:
            print("Game over.  Fireworks",observation["fireworks"],"Score=",episode_reward)
        game_scores.append(episode_reward)
    return sum(game_scores)/len(game_scores)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # TODO you could potentially code a genetic algorithm in here...
    num_players=4
    print("TEST start of main")

    chromosome=[0,2,5,6]
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(devnull):
            result=run(25,num_players,chromosome)
    print("chromosome",chromosome,"fitness",result)
```

and the result is as you can see below, only the two print calls in main have produced an output:

```
python chromosome_evaluator.py
TEST start of main
chromosome [0, 2, 5, 6] fitness 15.4
```

it is worth noting that the the agent class "RuleAgentChromosome" also has print functions which are not working.

any idea on what is causing this?

Comment: What did you expect to happen if you redirect your output to /dev/null?

Comment: I have only been using python for 2 months due to uni requirements, so I'm sorry if it is a very noob question.
Your answer is correct below, I will mark it once SO allows me to do so in five mins.

Comment: No need to apologize. Are you using python on Linux, or some other OS?

Comment: Hanabi framework is kinda buggy on windows, never got it to work on my machine, so I am coding this project and two follow-ups on Linux.

Comment: If you would like to understand why this error occured, I would recommend reading up on redirecting output in linux (stdout, stderr), and what `with` does.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and I will read more on them definitely, I did not write the code base which included them, I guess that's what you get for skipping lines you do not fully understand, especially in a new language hahaha

But thanks a million for your quick response, you're awesome !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(devnull):
            result=run(25,num_players,chromosome)
    print("chromosome",chromosome,"fitness",result)
```

I did not run your code, but if I understand this correctly, you redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` for `run()`. Therefore the output is discarded, and not shown.

Remove the two context managers (the lines starting with `with`). Then you should see the output of `run()`.